# How to get AWS account id as custom variable in serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

In serverless framework, I want to set the deployment bucket as

```
<project_name>-<stage>-<account_id>
```

I can get the stage using a custom variable, like:

```
custom:
    stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
```

but how can I get the aws account id? I already tried to used *serverless-pseudo-parameters*, like this below, without success.

```
custom:
    account_id: #{AWS::AccountId}
plugins:
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
```

Someone could help me to set the account id as a custom variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#reference-variables-in-javascript-files), to get the Account Id, you can use external js files:

```
// myCustomFile.js
module.exports.getAccountId = async (context) => {
    return context.providers.aws.getAccountId();
};
```

.

```
# serverless.yml
service: new-service
provider: aws
custom:
  accountId: ${file(../myCustomFile.js):getAccountId}
```

Comment: works, I have to set what the profile I want to use to get the account, but works...

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using Serverless with an "assumed role" where your IAM users are defined in a master AWS account and you're trying to deploy in a child account using a role from that child account: the **documented solution** - the one in the accepted answer above - **does not work**.

This setup in described in detail here: https://theithollow.com/2018/04/30/manage-multiple-aws-accounts-with-role-switching/. When using serverless with an `--aws-profile` that's configured to assume a role defined in another account, `sts.getCallerIdentity()` returns the account info of your master account from the default profile, and not the account of the assumed role.

To get the account ID of the assumed role (which is where we're deploying to), I did the following:

```
const { STS } = require('aws-sdk');

module.exports.getAccountId = async (context) => {
  // This loads the AWS credentials Serverless is currently using
  // They contain the role ARN of the assumed role
  const credentials = context.providers.aws.getCredentials();

  // init STS using the same credentials
  const sts = new STS(credentials);
  const identity = await sts.getCallerIdentity().promise();
  return identity.Account;
};
```

**Edit:**

Found an even better way, that is simpler than the one presented in Serverless docs and also works fine with assumed roles:

```
module.exports.getAccountId = async (context) => {
  return context.providers.aws.getAccountId();
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan C., I will try yours

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to access them below as per below example https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/

```
Resources:


- 'Fn::Join':
      - ':'
      - - 'arn:aws:logs'
        - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
        - Ref: 'AWS::AccountId'
        - 'log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*:*'
```

Comment: I found this at the documentation, but I would like to have the account id in the custom variables, your answer show how to get the account id in the Resource, i.e, with cloudformation

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your syntax is wrong. Try

```
custom:
    account_id: ${AWS::AccountId}
```

Because at least in the example that you provided you are using `#{AWS::AccountId}`

Notice the hashtag in your one?

Comment: Unfortunately `${AWS::AccounId}` only works in the Resource section, not in the custom. My syntax with `#` is the one used in the serverless-pseudo-parameters plugin.